# jsp set variable to always display

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm doing a mock project on a restaurant and I need to to display a list of Restaurants from database. I have a link from the main page direct to the restaurant list page by a Servlet and a method `getRestaurantList` to get all Restaurants. When the user click on this link they will be directed to the Restaurant page display all Restaurant. Here what I use to display the list:

Servlet

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
DataProcess dt = new DataProcess();
List<Restaurant> rlist = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
if("RestaurantList".equalsIgnoreCase(action))
{
    rlist = dt.getRestaurantList();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("rlist", rlist);
    response.sendRedirect("RestaurantList.jsp");
}
```

RestaurnatList.jsp

```
<c:forEach var="r" items="${sessionScope.rlist}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <a href="Restaurant.jsp">
                <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="${r.picture}" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h3>${r.restName}</h3>
            <h4>${r.phone}</h4>
            <p>${r.address}</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="Restaurant.jsp">View Restaurant</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>
</c:forEach>
```

This enable the user to see the list of Restaurant, but only in that particular session. If the user enter the URL directly then there is no Restaurant to display. Is there a way to always set the variable for the Restaurant List through out the application life cycle so that whenever the user enter the page it will always display the Restaurant list from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `restaurantList` into `application` context scope so that it is available from server startup till server shuts down (across all user sessions).

**Add the following ServletContextListener:**

```
public class MyProjectContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context) {
        //query from database and create rlist and then add to context object
        context.setAttribute("rlist", rlist);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent context) {

    }
}
```

**Add the Listener class to your Web.xml:**

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.myproject.MyProjectContextListener
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

In your JSP page:

```
<c:forEach var="r" items="${applicationScope.rlist}">
<!-- add other code as is -->
```

> How to call the Servlet so that it set the context scope? Does it
>   automatically set when starting the server?

`contextInitialized()` method will be invoked automatically by the server during the application start up, so you don't need to call any servlet.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer but how to call the Servlet so that it set the context scope? Does it automatically set when starting the server?

Comment: Updated my answer, so you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't  redirect to the JSP page. You should dispach the page by the servlet

```
RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("RestaurantList.jsp");
```

And put the list only in the request scope

```
request.setAttribute("rlist", rlist);
```

On your JSP page you can use `requestScope` instead of `sessionScope`

This solution never redirect to the JSP page. The JSP page will never shown in the navigationbar of the browser (only the content). The user can only bookmark the `http://yourhost/context?action=RestaurantList`

Comment: This does not seem to fix the problem. I want that even if the application start from the RestaurantList.jsp it should display the list